# Dropdown List from View Model Result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have a working example of a 'ViewModel' that I am thinking will work for a dropdown list. Currently I am using this to do a Foreach and it works fine for that but I need the same result in a dropdown on my form. I have played around with different ideas that I thought might work. None seem to do the trick. I do not have examples because I just normally read a bunch of posts and start throwing code at it to see what sticks. I am still learning so hopefully someone can either point me in the right direction or show me some code that will populate what I need. I believe I have everything in my ViewModel I need and I would like to stay away from Viewbag. Below is my 'ViewModel'.

This is the line I would like to use to populate the dropdown unless there is a better way.

```
result.Addresses = db.Addresses.Where(a => a.CompanyId == result.CompanyId);
```

EDIT - This is the now working dropdown for this 'ViewModel'

```
@Html.DropDownList("AddressId", new SelectList(Model.Addresses, "AddressId", "LocationName"), "Select Address user belongs to", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Here is the whole 'ViewModel'

```
    public class RegisterUserViewModel
{
    public static RegisterUserViewModel GetCompanyId(string userId, CustomerEntities db)
    {
        var qCust = from ad in db.Addresses

                    join anu in db.Users on ad.AddressId equals anu.AddressId
                    join cus in db.CompanyNames on ad.CompanyId equals cus.CompanyId
                    where (anu.Id == userId)
                    select new RegisterUserViewModel()
                    {
                        UserId = userId,
                        CompanyId = cus.CompanyId,
                        AddressId = ad.AddressId
                    };

        var result = qCust.SingleOrDefault();

        if (result != null)
        {
            result.Addresses = db.Addresses.Where(a => a.CompanyId == result.CompanyId);
        };

        return result;
    }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User Address")]
    public int AddressId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User Roles")]
    public string UserRoles { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Addresses> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

I am looking to have the AddressId as the value and LocationName as the Text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as below.

```
@Html.DropDownList("address", new SelectList(Model.Addresses, "AddressId", "LocationName"))
```

As you have mentioned into the comment that you're getting 2nd item as selected value after using `@Html.DropDownList(model => model.AddressId...`, so what happen here is it will automatically set selected value from your `model.AddressId`. Just check for that.

Now if you want to set default value then make sure that your `model.AddressId` has value same as your default select value.

Comment: This worked, thank you so much. However in my case the "address" needs to "AddressId". I did try something similar to this but had model => model.AddressId, new List<SelectListItem>(), "---Select---".

Comment: So after I marked this as correct, I noticed that it is pre selecting option 2 and calling it the selected item. It seems to be ignoring the default or placeholder value. Any idea why it would do this? I do not have a default value selected anywhere, also the selected 2 value is the last record for this case. Like it is calling the last item in the list as selected. thanks

Comment: So I went with a javascript window.onload to reset the value to 0.